# How to use artisan commands outside App folder?

Tags: laravel

I am structuring my app as modules, something like this

```
app/
bootstrap/
modules/
   -- Blog/
        --- Config/
        --- Console/
        --- Exceptions/
        --- Database/
                migrations/
                seeders/
                factories
        ---  Models/
        ---  Http/
                Controllers/
                Middleware/
        --- Providers/
        --- Resources/
        --- Routes/
                api.php
                web.php
        --- Tests/
   -- Backend/
   -- Frontend/
   -- Other modules etc..
config/
database/
public/
vendor/
resources/
other folders etc..
```

How can I use artisan to make controllers, migrations, providers ... etc, inside a specific module?

For example lets say I am in this location: `vagrant@homestead:~/code/myblog/modules/Blog$`

Is there a way to use artisan in this location? so when I do `php artisan make:controller TestController` it will be placed in `Blog/Http/Controllers`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `module:use` like below from you document root:

```
/**
* Use a specific module for artisan command line
*/
php artisan module:use Backend

/**
* Then create controller in selected module
*/
php artisan make:controller TestController
```